# Can't add attribute to ModelForm field at __init__

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model which returns the values in a ManyToMany field (`approvers`) as choices in an `Integerfield` (`step`):

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

class Task(models.Model):
    step = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField(
        get_user_model(),
    )

    @property
    def get_step_choices(self):
        CHOICES = []
        if self.approvers:
             CHOICES = [(a.id, a.email) for a in self.approvers.all()]
        return CHOICES

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Task, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('step')._choices = lazy(
            self.get_step_choices, list
        )()
```

However, the syntax I have used under **init** does not appear to render the choices attr to `step`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you intend to put `self._meta.get_field('step')` instead of `self._meta.get_field('status')`?

Comment: Thanks, edited - that was just a translation typo

Comment: When and how are you instantiating a task? Initializing the choices in the model `__init__` implies that the set of `approvers` is already populated in your database, but the `step` field is not. Is that correct? It might be clearer and safer to render the choices in either the model `save` method, or in a ModelForm.